# script to findstr and then inject next line with variable - can't quite get it working

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I've got a script I'm working on that checks a text file to match pc name, then match a port number.  That then info gets injected into an ini file for specific settings.  I'm using this in a Citrix setup.

Here's a piece of my test script:

```
:Set_Client_Name
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%1 in ('query session %USERNAME% ^| find ">"') do set ses_num=%%3
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%1 in ('reg query "HKCU\Volatile Environment\%ses_num%" /v CLIENTNAME') do set client_name=%%3


:CHECK
findstr /i /c:%client_name% "C:\star.txt"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end

:CREATE
set port=
set parse=findstr /i /c:%client_name% "C:\star.txt"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('"%parse%"') do (set port=%%a)


for /F %%G IN C:\hbowem32.ini DO (
findstr /i /c:"[0_Network Def.]"
echo Local Port=%port% >> C:\hbowem32.ini

)


:END
`
```

The :Set_Client_Name, :Check, and :Create portions work correctly.

I'm just doing something wrong with the next piece, and I'm not sure what it is.

I need to find the string [0_Network Def.] in the hbowem32.ini, and right after that, inject the %port% variable.  I can get it to add to the ini file at the bottom, but I need it to be able to inject this in the correct section of the ini.

I'm also wanting to add a section that pulls the client IP address (this is a Terminal Services/Citrix server) so it can be injected into a different ini/section.  I can't seem to get it to pull the user's workstation IP address.  It only pulls the IP address of the Citrix server.  I no longer have this section in my test script above, but figured I'd go ahead and ask since I'm here and already stuck.

Thanks for any insight and advice.

Comment: Does `Local Port=` already exist in the `ini` file and all you need to do is replace the `port` number?  Are you willing to use a second batch file to do the editing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/L` switch to the `FINDSTR` so that you are dealing with `L`iterals not (default) `R`egular expressions.